# POST https://localhost:44351/Common/SearchAvailableTechList 500(Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr.client

I am getting error in the browser console

```
POST https://localhost:44351/Common/SearchAvailableTechList 500(Internal Server Error)
```

SignalR FIle javascript Code:

```
function TechList(Id, Id2, Id3) {
        if (Id!= "" && Id2!= "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: $("#TechListUrl").val(),
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
```

after bundling in javascript, Its look like:

```
function TechList(n, t, i) {
    n != "" && t != "" && $.ajax({
        url: $("#TechListUrl").val(),
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
```

How can i get after bundling :

```
function TechList(n, t, i) {
    (n != "" && t != "")
{
$.ajax({
        url: $("#TechListUrl").val(),
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `$` is interfering with the Bundler. Try replace the `$` with `jQuery`.

Comment: Its Works for me Thanks